# Animate not queueing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have this working code for moving a heading icon forth and back if you hover over heading

```
jQuery('h1.heading').hover(
  function(){ 
    $icon = jQuery('.heading-icon', this);    
    if( ! $icon.is(':animated') ){
        $icon.animate({ "margin-left" : "+=7px" }, 200, function(){
          $icon.animate({ "margin-left" : "-=7px" }, 400, function(){ 
             $icon.css('margin-left','auto'); 
          } );
        } );
    }      
  },
  function(){} 
);
```

However if you hover faster over heading (faster than the animation is completed) it gets buggy and ends up moved away from original location.

I use onComplete functions, I even tried to use `! $('...').is(':animated')` as you can see above, did not help, so I thought at least I would reset the position after animation end so then even if it would get buggy it would at least reset to the original position after all animation would end... That worked only partially and still gets buggy and ends up in the wrong position...

So whats wrong?

How come that e.g. shake effect from jQuery UI enques good?

Note: I don't care if the animation runs a few times more, the goal is to make it stay at the right position when (all) the animation(s) end.

Any help ? :)

## EDIT

I finally reproduced the problem on JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yhJst/

 ==> try to hover up and down faster over the headings

## EDIT2

It doesn't seem to be happening when there is only one heading ... http://jsfiddle.net/scZcB/3/

Comment: Instead of using `hover` with an empty function, why not using `mouseenter`?

Comment: adivise = use html5/css3 animation instead of javascript!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem **or** i don't understand it... http://jsfiddle.net/scZcB/1/

Comment: @Eirenaios Can't use css3, crazy crossbrowsering  ;)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon does mouseenter solves the problem? I dont think so...

Comment: @jave.web no it doesnt, hence why i didn't post as an answer. It is just better (fact) and easier to read (opinion).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Problem reproduced, see the edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem, in your callback function, you are using animate on the `$icon` variable. But when you hover an other element, that variable is changed for the new hovered element.

Use `$(this)` in the callback or the natural queuing :

## Natural queuing

```
jQuery('h1.sc_blogger_title').on('mouseenter', function(){ 
    $icon = jQuery('.sc_title_bubble_icon', this);    
    if( ! $icon.is(':animated') ){
        $icon.animate({ "margin-left" : "+=7px" }, 200).animate({ "margin-left" : "-=7px" }, 400);
    }      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhJst/1/

## `$(this)`

```
jQuery('h1.sc_blogger_title').on('mouseenter', function(){ 
    $icon = jQuery('.sc_title_bubble_icon', this);    
    if( ! $icon.is(':animated') ){
        $icon.animate({ "margin-left" : "+=7px" }, 200, function(){
            $(this).animate({ "margin-left" : "-=7px" }, 400);
        });
    }      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhJst/2/

---

## Or use a local variable.

as you discovered, the current variable is a global one. Just add the keyword `var`.

```
jQuery('h1.sc_blogger_title').on('mouseenter', function(){ 
    var $icon = jQuery('.sc_title_bubble_icon', this);    
    if( ! $icon.is(':animated') ){
        $icon.animate({ "margin-left" : "+=7px" }, 200, function(){
            $icon.animate({ "margin-left" : "-=7px" }, 400, function(){ 
                $icon.css('margin-left','auto'); 
            } );
        } );
    }      
});
```

Comment: OR , just use mine but with the **`var`** keyword :D **`var`** `$icon = ...;`

Comment: @jave.web Oh... my... god... I've totaly missed that! I was looking at you code, found the problem but couldn't figured why. Convinced myself that it didn't matter since you can fix it with the code above. **I have never reallised it was a global variable!** Shame on me.

Comment: Well I understood that I forgot that is a global variable from your answer :D , anyway I used your code, its just shorter :) (but mine is working too with **var** keyword :)